# Dial number with Name from iOS app

Tags: ios, swift

I have found the answer on how to dial a number programmatically from an app.

```
@IBOutlet weak var phoneNumberTextField: UITextField!
```

...

```
@IBAction func phoneDialButton(sender: UIButton) {

    let phoneNumberToCall = phoneNumberTextField.text

    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "tel://\(phoneNumberToCall)")!
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)

}
```

What I am curious about is if I introduce a new field

```
@IBOutlet weak var phoneNameTextField: UITextField!
```

How would I go about putting that string as the name you are dialing when you make the call? Is it even possible?

Comment: What does it mean to dial a "name"?

Comment: for example if i called 555 555 5555 and the name was john it would say John up top then and the number underneath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for is not possible.  The name that comes up when you dial a number is either the contact name associated with that number, or a suggested contact from your email.  You would have to create a contact programmatically and associated the desired name with the number you want to dial, or update an existing contact if one for that phone number already exists.

Comment: Thank you for the answer